# Getting a type error for trying to sum a list of integers

Tags: python, list, sum, integer

I've just started learning python and I was trying to sum up a list of integers and I'm getting either "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'" or "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'"

I tried this

```
cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
user_hand = []
bot_hand = []

def deal_hand():
  user_hand.append(random.choices(cards, k=2))
  bot_hand.append(random.choices(cards, k=2))
  for i in user_hand:
    user_total = 0
    user_total += i
```

and

```
def deal_hand():
  user_hand.append(random.choices(cards, k=2))
  bot_hand.append(random.choices(cards, k=2))
  user_total = sum(user_hand)
```

as well as putting int(i) or sum(int(user_hand)), but that gives me the second error.

Comment: `random.choice`s is returning a List which you are appending to a List so forming a List of Lists. Hence error using `sum`

Comment: if you want to add multiple items to a list from another list and still have just a flat list (instead of a nested list-of-lists) then you can use `list.extend` instead of `list.append`

Answer (score 0):

[random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) returns `k` sized list of elements chosen from the *population*. `user_hand` and `bot_hand` already a list so calling append on it will create a list of list.

What you need to do is add individual elements return by `random.choices` to your list.

```py
import random

cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
user_hand = []
bot_hand = []

def deal_hand():
    for c in random.choices(cards, k=2):
        user_hand.append(c)

    for c in random.choices(cards, k=2):
        bot_hand.append(c)                                   
    user_total = sum(user_hand)
    print(user_total)
```

Comment: this would be better using `extend` instead of `append`-in-a-loop

Answer (score 0):

If you print `deal_hand` you'll something like `[[3, 2]]` because `random.choices` returns a `list` and you append it, you would need `user_hand.extend()`

Then I suggest you just create the list inside the method

```
cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]

def deal_hand():
    user_hand = random.choices(cards, k=2)
    bot_hand = random.choices(cards, k=2)
    user_total = 0
    for i in user_hand:
        user_total += i
```

Answer (score 0):

`random.choices` return a list, use `extend()` instead:

```
import random

cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]

user_hand = []
bot_hand = []

def deal_hand():
    user_hand.extend(random.choices(cards, k=2))
    bot_hand.extend(random.choices(cards, k=2))
    user_total = sum(user_hand)
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case, you have a user_hand that looks something like this: [[9, 5]] [[7, 10]] - that is, you have random.choices(cards, k=2) method generates an array of 2 random elements. And that's why adding the array to a variable of the 'int' type will be impossible, in this implementation, we will add the sum of elements in the array of arrays inside the loop and return the result from the function.

```
import random


cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
user_hand = []
bot_hand = []

def deal_hand():
  user_total = 0

  user_hand.append(random.choices(cards, k=2))
  bot_hand.append(random.choices(cards, k=2))

  for i in user_hand:
    user_total += sum(i)
  return user_total

print(deal_hand())
```

Comment: `sum(i)` is not the way to do